# Set option just for one command

Tags: vim

I was looking for a way to set `virtualedit=block` before executing visual block select with additional binding `g<C-v>` and after that turning it off.

There are few things in my workflow that require that behavior. I didn't find anything after some research. So currently I have this in my vimrc.

```
nnoremap g<C-v> :setl virtualedit=block<CR><C-v>
nnoremap <C-v> :setl virtualedit=<CR><C-v>
```

Another example is to disable `incsearch` for custom command

```
nnoremap <silent> K :setl nois<CR>:grep! "\b<C-R><C-W>\b"<CR>:setl is<CR>
```

So my question is, is there right or just better than the one I came up with way to set option just for one command and switch it back after command is done?

**Update**
Here is example of code for idea that @Kent suggested

```
function! Example()
  let &l:virtualedit="block"
  exe "normal \<C-v>"
  let &l:virtualedit=""
endfunction
```

But this way does not work for cases like in first example

Answer (score 3):

one way to go is wrap in function, and make your mapping call the function:

```
function! Example()
  let &option="whatever"
  logic ...
  let &option="whatever else"
endfunction
```

or you can concatenate the commands : `setlocal .. | command | setlocal ...`

Comment: I thought about creating function. But this function will not work for cases like in first example.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev yes, it should be `endfunction`. ;-)